# Algorithm for finding lowest memory order of operations

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, memory, memory-management

I am have a large list of math operations involving multiplication of arrays. Right now I allocate the memory of all arrays, then carry out all operations and deallocate arrays at the end of all of the operations. However, this is not necessary as some arrays are no longer needed after certain points. Figuring out how to manage these equations is easy with 3 or 4 of them, but hard with 100's of equations. So I want to find the ordering or operations that maintains the lowest memory cost.

To give an example, lets assume I have arrays 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', and 'F'. Assume I have the following operations:

```
A  = B * C
E += D * A
E += C * F
Return E
```

We can see that the ordering of the last two operations do not depend on each other so their order can be reversed. Lets assume that the produce for 'A' must be done before E and that in the full list of operations this is always done. Also, lets assume that these equations are factorized so we cannot, for example, replace the second equation by `E += D * B * C`. Now in this example we could allocate/deallocate arrays as follows:

```
allocate A, B, C
   A = B * C
deallocate B
allocate E, D
   E += D * A
deallocate D, A
allocate F
   E += C * F
deallocate C, F
return E
```

However depending on the sizes of the arrays and because the order of the last two operations does not matter, it may be more efficient to

```
allocate A, B, C
   A = B * C
deallocate B
allocate E, F
   E += C * F
deallocate C, F
allocate  D
   E += D * A
deallocate D, A
return E
```

Is there any algorithm that is helpful in determining the path of operations that maintains the lowest memory allocation? For an added difficulty, assume this is an routine in which some of the arrays persistently allocated and are passed and returned with or without being changed.

Comment: Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. You should remove that portion of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard problem, but for optimization you just need a likely to be good answer.  And greedy should be reasonable.

You have a list of operations (allocate, deallocate, equation) and a partial order from the dependencies.

The actual order in which you will do things is a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of those operations.

The algorithm for sorting that I recommend is Kahn's algorithm.  In short, it is based on having a list of operations that can come next, with a list of how many dependencies are left on the ones that remain.  When you've satisfied the last dependency, you put it on the available list.  The trick is in choosing how to put it on the available list.

First, generate a full working list of operations with dependencies.  Your operations are allocations, equations, and deallocations.  You must allocate before use or assignment.  Deallocate after all uses and assignments.  And any assignment that comes before a use must remain before that use.

Once you have that list, do a topological sort and call the result A.  Next do a topological sort where every time you pick off the free list the one that came last in A.  Call the result B.  The interesting thing about these two sorts is that if x < y in both sorts, then there is some chain of logical dependencies between x and y.

Now for each variable, assign a weight corresponding to how much memory it takes.  Assign 2x the weight as the cost of the allocation.  Assign -weight to the deallocation as a payment.  And divide -weight evenly among the steps that have to be between allocation and deallocation as additional payments.

And now we do our third topological sort.  This time we pick the lowest cost / highest payment option at every step.  So we're trying not to assign big chunks of memory, and as soon as we do, we're trying to prioritize freeing it.

The result won't be perfect.  But it should be pretty good.

Comment: would you please consider my question : some times ago you comment one of my question that was closed. now after some times I copy your comments here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65644586/number-of-inversion-when-we-have-min-heap#65645532 please see.